# Can't get ODATA v4 actions attached to an entity to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, odata

So, I tried following the instructions [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) to implement an action on my Job entity, but for the life of me, I can't get OData to recognize it.

The Action is pretty simple.  Just a toggle for a boolean:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Pause([FromODataUri]int key)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return BadRequest();
    }

    Job job = _context.Job.Find(key);
    if (job == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    job.IsPaused = !job.IsPaused;
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(acquisition.IsPaused);
}
```

And it is defined in my WebApiConfig as:

```
var jobEntity = builder.EntityType<Job>();
var pause = jobEntity.Action("Pause");
pause.Returns<bool>();
```

So, I should be able to POST to //url/odata/Job(key)/Pause to call it.  Unfortunately, it doesn't recognize the Pause action, listing it with a response of entityset/key/unresolved action.  If I try to use the ODataRoute attribute on it:

```
[ODataRoute("Job({key})/Pause")]
```

It chokes on the Pause, giving me a compile error of "The path template 'Job({key})/Pause' on the action Pause in controller 'Job' is not a valid OData path template.  Found an unresolved path segment 'Pause' in the OData path template."

Now, if I make it an unbound action:

```
var pause = builder.Action("Pause");
pause = Parameter<int>("key");
pause.Returns<bool>();
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("Pause")]
public IHttpActionResult Pause(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return BadRequest();
    }

    var key = Convert.ToInt32(parameters["key"]);
    Job job = _context.Job.Find(key);
    if (job == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    job.IsPaused = !job.IsPaused;
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(acquisition.IsPaused);
}
```

It works just fine.  So, why can't I bind this to the Job entity?  Just as a note I did try adding ODataActionParameters, even tho I don't have any parameters to see if that changed anything.  It didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI the [bound to entityset examples](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support), from that, you can see that you need a namespace, you should request like: `odata/Job(key)/Default.Pause`, bound action doesn't need ODataRoute.

Comment: After struggling with it, that did seem to be the problem.  My followup question is, what is the point of the namespace?  As far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to serve any useful purpose and it is just there to make my life difficult.

Comment: And then I add the change to ExtensionlessUrlHandler to recognize the period, and it breaks my Angularjs web site.

Comment: Found I needed to change the name for it to be accepted.  What a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling with it...

I tried to apply the Fan Ouyang's suggestion without success...

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support

**OData route config:**

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<tblMeetings> MeetingsType = builder.EntitySet<tblMeetings>("Meetings").EntityType;
MeetingsType.HasKey(p => p.Meeting_ID);

var MeetingsFunctionBadges = MeetingsType.Collection.Function("Badges");
MeetingsFunctionBadges.Parameter<int>("key");
MeetingsFunctionBadges.Returns<List<tblBadges>>();
```

**The meeting's controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("Meetings({key})/Badges")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBadges(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

**An then the error...**

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.OData.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The path template 'Meetings({key})/Badges' on
>   the action 'GetBadges' in controller 'Meetings_OData' is not a valid
>   OData path template. Found an unresolved path segment 'Badges' in the
>   OData path template 'Meetings({key})/Badges'.

Comment: Try [ODataRoute("Meetings({key})/Default.Badges")]
The Default prefix appears to allow OData v4 to resolve the path segment.